# Groovy Console read input

Tags: groovy, input, groovy-console

I'm just starting to learn Groovy and I am experimenting in GroovyConsole.

Is there a way I can read user input? I have tried the code below but I get an error.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))

print "Input:"

input = br.readLine()

println "You entered: $input"
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Exception thrown
17-Apr-2012 02:52:39 org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize

WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:

java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Is there anything I need to import?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: When does this error occur? How did you start `groovyConsole`?

Comment: This error occurs when I run the script from GroovyConsole. I just started GroovyConsole with the 'Start GroovyConsole' shortcut.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Try running from terminal, e.g. `> groovyConsole` then standard input is received through the terminal. This might be of use to you http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Input-from-GroovyConsole-td342416.html.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Though I am still a bit confused on how to run a script from the terminal? How do I access it?

Answer (score 44):

I got here trying to find out the easiest way to read user input from the command line...
I found the answer [elsewhere](http://mrhaki.blogspot.se/2010/09/gradle-goodness-get-user-input-values.html), will post here to document the 'real' Groovy way as it's still missing:

```
def username = System.console().readLine 'What is your name?'
println "Hello $username"
```

As Larry Battle says, if using the groovy console, make sure to look at the background 'black' window for the output and to type input.

**EDIT**

In an environment where [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) is not available, such as running from your IDE, probably, use this instead:

```
println "What is your name?"
println "Your name is ${System.in.newReader().readLine()}"
```

Answer (score 25):

```
def readln = javax.swing.JOptionPane.&showInputDialog
def username = readln 'What is your name?'
println "Hello $username."
```

Comment: This is very cool and succint, how do you get the "ok/cancel" value? Nevemind, got it.. it returns null if you hit cancel.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice one. Could also be `import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog` and `def username = showInputDialog 'What is your name?'`

Answer (score 12):

Your code works.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
print "Input:"
def userInput = br.readLine()
println "You entered: $userInput"
```

Assuming you're on windows, the only problem is that the input is being read from the console in the background that is launched before groovyconsole.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this, which works at the command-line of any o/s, but also in the GoovyConsole - where it pops up a dialog [as noted in a previous post]:

```
def cons = System.console()
def yn
if (cons) {
    yn = {((cons.readLine(it + " (y/n) ")?:"n").trim()?:"n")?.charAt(0).toLowerCase().toString() }
} else {
    cons = javax.swing.JOptionPane.&showInputDialog
    yn = {((cons(it + " (y/n) ")?:"n").trim()?:"n")?.charAt(0).toLowerCase().toString() }
}
if (yn("Did you want to do something?") == 'y')
    ...do something here!...
```

Comment: sweet!! Haven't tried it out (about to..) but cheers if it works!

Answer (score 2):

if your System.console() is null, you can

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.nextLine()
```