# How to use Console.readInteger() in GroovyConsole?

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

my groovy script code is like this:

```
import console.*
def data=Console.readInteger()
println "data:${data}"
```

But when I ran it, I got exception:

> Exception thrown
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.io.Console.readInteger() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

How to read an integer from basic input? Thanks a lot?

Comment: Have you seen - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184091/groovy-console-read-input

Comment: It helped me! Thank you very much!